# How to change displayed stats?

Tags: apex-legends

Whenever we are presented with either our own squad or with the current champion and their squad at least one of them has more than one stat shown. These stats can include zip-line distance, walked distance, distance walked, enemies hit with smoke grenade and more.

As I only have the kills per character displayed, I am wondering how I can change the stats displayed.

**So the question is, how can I customize the stats displayed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to legends and pick any legend, on the top of the screen under the name you can see 4 tabs(skin, banner, quips, finishes)

If you select the banner tab you can change everything about the banner. These thing need to be unlocked. You get one for each category at the start.

Trackers are the stats you see displayed like kills, distances grappled etc. These are all unlocked through lootboxes.

Badges are the symbols and can be unlocked by perfoming actions in the game, like res 2 squadmates in 1 game, win while kill leader etc.